# Why can't my program loop over a file certain amount of time?

Tags: python, file, hash, md5

I am working on a Python project, in which the user enters an md5 hash(of a password) and the program compares the hash with the rock-you file hash(manually converting word to md5 hash), if it found one then it will tell the user the word if it didn't, then it will say that it didn't find any passwords that matched. If you are wondering, rockyouu is a file with 14 million passwords.

Here's the code:

```
import hashlib
import os
import time
import threading

def show_loading_screen():
    animation = "|/-\\|"
    idx = 0
    while not loading_complete:
        print("Cracking Possible Passwords... " + animation[idx % len(animation)], end="\r")
        idx += 1
        time.sleep(0.1)
loading_complete = False
attempt = 0
user_hash = input("Enter your MD5 Hash to Decrypt: ")
os.system('cls')
loading_screen_thread = threading.Thread(target=show_loading_screen)
loading_screen_thread.start()
found = False
with open("C:\\Users\\Shameer Kashif\\Desktop\\Python\\rockyouu.txt", "r") as file:
    try:
        for line in file:
            attempt += 1
            passwrd = line.strip()
            hashed = hashlib.md5(passwrd.encode()).hexdigest()
            if hashed == user_hash:
                loading_complete = True
                loading_screen_thread.join()
                found = True
                os.system('cls')
                print("Password cracked after " + str(attempt) + " attempts.\nYour password is : " + passwrd + "\nYour Hash is : " + user_hash)
                time.sleep(10)
                break
        if not found:
            print("Hash is not availabe in our database")
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        loading_complete = True
        os.system('cls')
        print("Illegal Chracters in line ", attempt)
```

The problem is that for some reason, my program can't loop over the line "230816" of file `rockyouu.txt`. You can see in my code, I used `try:` and `except:` in my code and wrote:

```
print("Illegal Chracters in line ", attempt)
```

to know exactly in which line is there a problem, but when scroll there, there wasn't any "special characters" in that line.

I tried to convert the rockyouu file into utf-8 text file, that's why there is two "u" instead of one because I was saving a file. But nothing has happened.

Comment: just because you can't see them doesn't mean they aren't there

Comment: Please stop using MD5 to hash passwords. It was old 20 years ago

Comment: Did you try `for line in file.readlines():`?

Comment: @Jib Why would that be any better? That will try to decode the entire file all at once, and you won't know which line the problem is on. Also, it will have to construct a list with 14 million elements.

Comment: Your try/except is swallowing the error message. Please change the except to `except UnicodeDecodeError as e:`, change the print to `print('Illegal characters in line ', attempt, e)`, and provide the output. The error message will report the problematic byte as well as its position in the line.

Comment: Don't forget that the line number in `attempt` is 0-based.

Comment: Look at the line with a hex editor.

Answer (score 0):

Specify latin-1 encoding when opening the original rockyou.txt file.

Also, a sequential approach to "cracking" the user-specified MD5 hash is going to take a very long time. With judicious use of a multiprocessing pool the duration can be dramatically improved.

So, ignoring the animation thread and how the user input is acquired we come to this:

```
import hashlib
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import perf_counter

md5 = '614bea11f3f8f38d6547c79786a7e0b1'


def crackit(pwd):
    if hashlib.md5(pwd.encode()).hexdigest() == md5:
        print(pwd)


def main():
    with open(file='/Volumes/G-Drive/Downloads/rockyou.txt', mode='r', encoding='latin-1') as passwords:
        with Pool() as pool:
            pool.map_async(crackit, map(str.strip, passwords), chunksize=10_000).wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = perf_counter()
    main()
    end = perf_counter()
    print(f'Duration={end-start:.2f}s')
```

**Output:**

```
beautiful100
Duration=3.86s
```

**Note:**

The rockyou.txt used here is the original unmodified file acquired from Kaggle